# Why is the regular expression returning an error in python?

Tags: python, regex

Am trying the following regular expression in python but it returns an error

```
import re
...

#read a line from a file to variable line
# loking for the pattern 'WORD' in the line ...

m=re.search('(?<=[WORD])\w+',str(line))
m.group(0)
```

i get the following error:

**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'**

Answer (score 5):

This is happening because the regular expression wasn't matched. Therefore m is None and of course you can't access group[0]. You need to first test that the search was successful, before trying to access group members.

Comment: It's actually m that is None. (Minor nit.)

Answer (score 5):

Two issues:

1. your pattern does not match, therefore `m` is set to `None`, and `None` has no `group` attribute.
2. I believe you meant either:

   ```
   m= re.search(r"(?<=WORD)\w+", str(line))
   ```

   as entered, or

   ```
   m= re.search(r"(?P<WORD>\w+)", str(line))
   ```

   The former matches "abc" in "WORDabc def"; the latter matches "abc" in "abc def" and the match object will have a `.group("WORD")` containing "abc". (Using r"" strings is generally a good idea when specifying regular expressions.)

Answer (score 2):

[re.search documentation says](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.search):

> Return **None** if no position in the string matches the pattern; note that this is different from finding a zero-length match at some point in the string.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> help(re.search)
Help on function search in module re:

search(pattern, string, flags=0)
    Scan through string looking for a match to the pattern, returning
    a match object, or None if no match was found.
```

Look at the last line: **returning None if no match was found**

Answer (score 1):

BTW, your regular expression is incorrect.
If you look for 'WORD', it should be just 'WORD'. `str` is also extraneous. Your code should look like this:

```
m = re.search('WORD', line)
if m:
    print m.group[0]
```

Your original regexp will return probably unexpected and undesired results:

```
>>> m = re.search('(?<=[WORD])\w+', 'WORDnet')
>>> m.group(0)
'ORDnet'
```